# fftw Cross Compile for linux angstrom ARM8

Tags: linux, compilation, arm, cross-compiling, fftw

I have a [processor board](http://pironex.de/de/produkte/ipc/prozessormodule/pia-am335x-pm.html) and cross compile with my code QTcreator. The compiler works and I got all my code on the board (C and C++).

To calculate a fft I use the fftw library. On my Linux PC everything works fine. I installed it as mentioned in the manual of fftw (./configure -> make -> make install)

Now I downloaded the fftw arm library to get it on my board.

For the fftw_arm I tried to install it like this way

```
sudo ./configure --with-slow-timer --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --enable-single --enable-neon "CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp"
```

but every time  I got the message

```
configure: error: in `/home/manuel/Downloads/fftw-3.2.2-arm':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I tried to use the path to the same compiler as the QT Environment use to build my code for the board.

In the config.log there is just the remark that the library cannot found.

But I copied the path from the QT compiler, so it must be there.

Furthermore is it necessary to install the fftw_arm with --enable... 
or can I just install it like the fftw 3.3.6 for my linux pc. (./configure make make install )

Of course I used sudo every time.

Comment: Oh sorry the error is at this point in the log file:

configure:4102: /usr/local/oecore-x86_64/sysroots/x86_64-angstromsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc -V >&5
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: fatal error: no input files


anybody experience with this problem?